# Assigning lineEdit to Variable for QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins

I am trying to create my first QGIS 3 plugin, I am using Plugin Builder and Qt Designer, I want to add a variable named name with lineEdit to be able to use the information entered later, however, I receive the following error:

> name = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
>
> AttributeError: 'Etiquetas_layout' object has no attribute 'dlg'

here's my code:

```
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
  
    name = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
 
    # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
    # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the 
    plugin is started
    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
        self.dlg = Etiquetas_layoutDialog()

    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code.
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving this line :

```
name = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
```

into the if result: statement